# Dropdown box with php variables

Tags: javascript, php, datatable

How can I make a filter drop-down box with `$row['clinic_id']. "-" . $row['clinic_name']` to display. For example , 1-MedCare and so on, I'm not even sure where to start, any ideas? And I also want that when i click on a certain option is filters out in my table and displays just that option

Comment: With basic PHP and HTML tutorials, would be my suggestion. A dropdown box is done with the [HTML select element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you would like to create a drop down with PHP variables. Here's how: put the following in a PHP file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['clinic_id'] . ' - ' . $row['clinic_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['clinic_id']; ?></option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's how you can display divs depending on the selected drop down element:

```js
document.getElementById('options').onchange = function() {
    var i = 1;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById(i);
    while(myDiv) {
        myDiv.style.display = 'none';
        myDiv = document.getElementById(++i);
    }
    document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
};
```

```css
div {
    display: none;   
}
```

```html
<select name="options" id="options">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>

<div id="1" style="display:block">First Text</div>
<div id="2">Second Text</div>
<div id="3">Third Text</div>
```

Comment: yes; but I want them both to be display in one dropbox separating them is a "-"

Comment: i have edited my answer

Comment: Can I make it filter out my table when i chose an option?

Comment: Yes but are you sure you have only one option to choose from ?

Comment: yes I want it to filter out through the id but I have to display the name next to it, so users would know the name before choosing.

Comment: I have added a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in your option tag

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['clinic_id']."-".$row['clinic_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['clinic_id']."-".$row['clinic_name']; ?></option>
```

Comment: I did it, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['clinic_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['clinic_id']; ?>-<?php echo $row['clinic_name']; ?></option>
  </select>
```

otherwise

```
 <select>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['clinic_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['clinic_id']."-". $row['clinic_name']; ?></option>
      </select>
```

Comment: would it filter out my table?

Comment: @jasmine825 you need to use JS to display content depending on selected dropdown. However here you only have one dropdown...

Comment: would you please share your entire code@jasmine825